# gson + retrofit2 : parse special characters

Tags: android, encoding, character-encoding, gson, retrofit2

My response contains special characters like English word syllables (eg. ri,peɪtri'eɪʃʌn) which gson cannot parse them and throws exception with `Expected begin_object but was string at line 1 column 199 path $` error message. I tried encoding the response with utf-8 by writing below custom deserializer but did not worked. It is terminated immediately when `gson.fromJson()` is called.

```
public class WordResponseDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Define> {

@Override
public Define deserialize(JsonElement json, Type typeOfT,
                          JsonDeserializationContext context) throws JsonParseException {
    Log.d(getClass().getSimpleName(), "In Deserialize");
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String string = json.toString();
    byte[] bytes = string.getBytes();
    String enString = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    Define gDefine = gson.fromJson(enString, Define.class); //Crashing here
    return gDefine;
}
}
```

Can Gson parse these special characters? What is the possible way?

Comment: @Lampard Did not worked

Comment: I believe the problem shouldn't be special characters. Have you just tried to deserialize "json" directly without converting to string. gson.fromJson(json, Define.class);

Comment: Yes I tried, got same error.

Answer (score 1):

**Change this portion of code:**

```
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes();
String enString = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
Define gDefine = gson.fromJson(enString, Define.class); //Crashing here
```

**with this:**

```
byte[] bytes = string.getBytes("ISO-8859-1");
String enString = new String(bytes, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
Define gDefine = gson.fromJson(enString, Define.class);
```